# Navigating through a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, location, closest

I have a dictionary called "locations". A function I'm writing for the dictionary is set up in the format (d, description, current) where 'd' references the dictionary, 'description' references a string describing the location we are looking for, and 'current' references the spot we currently are in the dictionary as a pair of coordinates (x,y).

Basically, each location has multiple positions in the dictionary each with its own pair of coordinates and my goal is to find the closest position to where we currently are in the dictionary (current). The strategy is to use the distance formula to calculate this.

For example if we were looking for the nearest gas station and we were currently at (2,2), the function should return (3,1) for the nearest station if the two stations were at (3,1) and (1,4) as (3,1) is closer to (2,2)  Any advice on my current code would be appreciated.

Code:

```
def closest(d, description, current):
    current_location = (x, y)
    d = {(3,1):'gas', (1,4):'gas', (2,1):'food', (5,5):'food'}
    distancesFromCurrent = [distanceFormula(z, current_location) for z in places]
    for z in d:
    if z < minimum float:
        return z
```

My current code has no errors but is definitely not working correctly. It is just returning 0,0 and I'm not sure how I can fix it to return the coordinates of the closest location to our current position.

Comment: don't give variables the same name functions..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out just fixed it

Comment: I want to add I think the problem is locating the closest location. Somehow I think I'm supposed to use the description string to locate it but not sure how this would be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering the comments, here is my solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Nov  6 21:42:22 2016

@author: michaelcurrin
"""

import math

def findDistance(A, B):
    """
    In 2D space find the distance between two co-orinates is 
    known as Eucliciean distance.
    Args
        A: tuple or list of x and y co-ordinates 
            e.g. (1,2) e.g. [1,2]
        B: as A.
    Retuns
        distance: float. Decimal value for shortest between A and B
    """
    x = (A[0] - B[0])
    y = (A[1] - B[1])
    distance = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # square root

    # remove comment if you want to see this outputted
    # print distance 

    return distance


def GetClosestPlace(places, loc, feature):
    """find shortest distance between current location and each locations 
    but only ones which have the desired feature"""

    # add distance from current location to each location
    for index in range(len(places)):

        # only continue if feature exists at place
        if feature in places[index]['features']:

            # calculate
            distance = findDistance(loc,
                                    places[index]['location'])
        else:
            # this is to represent n/a for now as every location needs a distance
            # for this version, so that it will not be chosen
            distance = 1000 

            # add calculated distance to existing dictionary for location
        places[index]['distance'] = distance    


    # find shortest distance and return details for that place

    allDistances = [x['distance'] for x in places]
    shortestDistance = min(allDistances)

    for place in places:
        if place['distance'] == shortestDistance:
            return place


placesList = [dict(name='foo',location=(0,3), features=['gas', 'food']),
              dict(name='bar',location=(4,6), features=['food', 'hospital']),
              dict(name='abc',location=(0,9), features=['gas','barber']),
              dict(name='xyz',location=(2,2), features=['food','barber'])
              ]

currentLocation = (5,9)
desiredFeature='food'

closestPlace = GetClosestPlace(placesList, currentLocation, desiredFeature)

print 'Current location: %s' % str(currentLocation)
print 'Desired feature: %s ' % desiredFeature
print
print 'The closest place is...'
print 'Name: %s' % closestPlace['name']
print 'Location %s' % str(closestPlace['location'])
print 'Distance %f' % closestPlace['distance']
# join multiple features in the list with commas
print 'Features: %s' % ', '.join(closestPlace['features'])

"""
OUTPUT

Current location: (5, 9)
Desired feature: food 

The closest place is...
Name: bar
Location (4, 6)
Distance 3.162278
Features: food, hospital
"""
```

Comment: In my 2nd version of the above I've corrected a flaw in the features and improved the output formatting . Plus I added another example for places.

Comment: You have been a huge help I've given you best answer. I'm getting one error now and I'm not sure why. It says: line 45, in GetClosestPlace
    if feature in d[index]['features']:
KeyError: 0. I'm not sure what is causing the key error

Comment: Maybe because you're on Python 3.x and I'm 2.7? That will affect running first line, the print statements and maybe line you are getting an error?

Comment: Paste more of your update code on http://pastebin.com/ or Github.com and I can check out the error.

Comment: Thanks I uploaded my code and the error to pastebin. I changed the parameter names to fit the function I need to write http://pastebin.com/4npxAyn5

Comment: Cool thanks. 

Add in this just before the **if** statement to see what value you have set for **here**.
`print here`
`print type(here)`

It looks like you are getting the error on **here** because **here** is not defined (or maybe in the wrong format).
I can see only the functions and not the line where you execute **closest**. But make sure **here** comes in as a string like 'gas'.



Also note that the program assumes there will be at least once match for feature, so do some error catching on that to return 'no match' or something like that otherwise the script might crash.

Comment: No problem thanks again for all the help I think I've figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the dictionary input to calculate results for place names against their distance from the current location as a single float (or decimal).

Something like

```
current_location = (x, y)
distancesFromCurrent = [distanceFormula(z, current_location) for z in places]
```

Where distanceFormula would be using you distance calc in function.

Once you have that for **all** places inputted, then you can do another loop find the **minimum** float value in the dictionary and return its corresponding place name and its co-ordinate location (from the original input).

I think you could change from dictionary to list input to be in this format below. (if you have anything data like this already to show us that would help too)

```
placesList = [dict(name='abc',location=(0,3), features=['gas station','mall', 'police dept', 'fire dept']),
              dict(name='xyz',location=(4,5), features=['police dept', 'hospital']),
             #etc.
             ]
```

Then your function would have find the closest the location but first filter out the locations which have the feature which matches your description.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm still really confused. Is z equal to the description string? Would the nearest location always have the minimum float value? How exactly would I specifically search for the minimum float value for a location with a specific description? Here is what one of the test cases is looking for if it is helpful in explaining: closest({(3,1):'gas', (1,4):'gas', (2,1):'food', (5,5):'food'},'food',(1,4)) == (2,1).

Comment: I used z as co-ordinate e.g. (1,4), not as description.

Comment: oh I thought the place names were cities and town. Does that matter at all as a label for the user or it is only co-ordinate against service at co-ord?

Comment: I think the names are meant to instruct the function on what to search for. For example if the name is 'Food' it should search for the nearest food location to the current location. I liked your idea of changing from dictionary to list so I could put all the food place coordinates together, all the gas places together, etc. But I still don't know how I would find the minimum float value for only one category of places and compare that to the current location

Comment: I would recommend using the location e.g. (3,1) as the dictionary key, since you could food and gas at once location which would mean

Comment: x = {(3,1):'food', (3,1): 'gas'} would be useless because it uses the same key twice. In fact I tested that and then x becomes the latest once i.e. gas only.

Comment: sorry I meant "I would recommend AGAINST the location as the dictionary key"

Comment: I just edited my code to include some of your advice. Am I on the right track? I believe that is the way the dictionary is supposed to be set up. Those are the only values and the test cases just search for which one of those is closest to the current location

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to find the minimum float value so I just included where that should be done and how I think the logic would be done